# How to get the xml content of a node as a string?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Using PHP's DOM functions, how do you convert a DOM Node's contents into a string?

```
<foo>
    Blah blah <bar baz="1">bah</bar> blah blah
</foo>
```

**Given `foo` as the current context node, how do you get `'Blah blah <bar baz="1">bah</bar> blah blah'` as a string?** Using `$node->textContent` or `$node->nodeValue` just returns the text nodes, not the `<bar baz="1">` bits.

Basically, the equivalent of Javascript's `innerHTML` property...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new DOMDocument from the `<foo>` node and parse it as XML or HTML:

```
function getInnerHTML($node) {
    $tmpDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $block = $tmpDoc->importNode($node->cloneNode(true),true);
    $tmpDoc->appendChild($block);
    $outer = $tmpDoc->saveHTML();
    //this will remove the outer tags
    return substr($outer,strpos($outer,'>')+1,-(strlen($node->nodeName)+4)); 
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds. I've posted the SimpleXML way instead, though this is rather trivial.