# Get HTML from DOM and store it in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I'm trying to get *the content of a certain div* from a page and store it in my db. I did the following:

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new SmartDOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);    
$div_tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($div_tags as $element) {
    if(strpos($element->getAttribute('itemprop'), 'description') !== false)
        $description = $element->nodeValue;
}
```

I used [SmartDOMDocument](http://beerpla.net/projects/smartdomdocument-a-smarter-php-domdocument-class/) because it handles UTF-8 better than `DOMDocument`.

Now, this will give me the `text of the element` *without* the tags. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/999967/543711) and it did give me the text with the tags. However, when I tried to store it in my db, I couldn't!

Is there a better way to get the `utf-8 text with the tags` from the element and store it properly in a db?

**EDIT:**
the insert statement is pretty simple:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `MyTable`.`content` (`description`) VALUES ('$description')";
$r=mysql_query($q); 
var_dump($r);
```

Comment: `when I tried to store it in my db, I couldn't!` why? any errors? what happens?

Comment: I tried `var_dump()` the result and it gave me `bool(false)`. Nothing else.

Comment: Well looking at your code, you have a foreach, a if and the element do you want to catch multiple items or just one ? if that is the case make a break after the if to leave the foeach as it may be hitting another element that is empty perhaps.

Comment: You are right. But I know I got the right item. `$description` is returning the expected result.

Comment: Could you add code that is responsible for DB-operations?

Comment: See the edit. It is a simple insert. And it works when I do `$description = $element->nodeValue;`

Comment: @iturki use `mysql_real_escape_string($element)`, also using DomDocument instead of smart, does it return the HTML you wanted ? if so it may be easier for you to just use mb and convert anything needed back to utf8

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` takes a string as a parameter, not a DOMElement!

Comment: @iturki not after you take the nodeValue as it turns into a string, have you tried getting the element nodevalue using DomDocument alone ?

Comment: Yes. I tried both. Unfortunately, both returned the string _without_ tags.

Comment: @iturki have you tried using `parentNode` `$element->parentNode->nodeValue`

Comment: Although this will return unwanted data, still `nodeValue` returned the text only.

Answer (score 0):

Try **var_dump**-ing the $element to see if it has other properties than **nodeValue**. There should also be something as **HTMLvalue**, getHTML or other similar property.

Comment: I tried that. It returned `object(DOMElement)#8 (0) { }`. Odd!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use textContent instead of nodeValue. And do not forget about escaping (I assume use mysql_real_escape_string in this case)

Comment: Apparently, `textContent` is no difference than `nodeValue`. The tags are removed.